# Could not load type FSharpList from assembly FSharp.Core in Unity

Tags: .net, unity-game-engine, f#, functional-programming

I am trying to use F# from within Unity ([the game engine](http://unity3d.com), not the [Microsoft dependency injection framework](http://unity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Unity3&referringTitle=Home)) and so far it's all gone well -- I can compile the files to a DLL, put that DLL next to `FSharp.Core.dll` inside the Assets directory, and Unity picks it all up and executes any code I've defined in there.

My first hiccup came when I tried to use a list.  Adding the following:

```
static member template =
  [ "some strings"
    "inside an array" ]
  |> String.concat "\n"
```

Causes the following error to come up in Unity:

```
TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1' from assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

The version of `FSharp.Core.dll` that I have in my Assets directory is the one packaged with Unity, but I tried changing it to one of a few others (like the one that comes with the redistributable), to no avail.  All that changed is the reported version number: `4.0.0.0`, `4.3.1.0`, and `2.3.5.0` respectively.

I am fairly new to both Unity and F#, so there may be something fundamental I'm missing here.  Should `` FSharpList`1 `` be defined in the `FSharp.Core.dll` assembly?  If not, where?  If so, why can't Unity seem to get at it?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried the always helpful `Add-BindingRedirect`(http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-manager-console-powershell-reference) - or better: can you give a short snippet where we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: btw: this more or less adds some entries into your app.config that should look similar to this example here (look for fsharp): https://github.com/CarstenKoenig/EventSourcing/blob/master/src/EventSourcing.Tests/app.config

Comment: oh and another tipp: it's always painful to use the stuff begining with `FSharp` (`FSharpList`,`FSharpOption`, `FSharpFun`, ...) from C# - you should rewrite your public facing api (if you want to use it from C#) into more friendlier stuff - in this example just convert into a sequence (`IEnumerable` in C#) - also it's really strange that Unity complains about a list when your example will return only a String - my guess is that the problem lies elsewhere - maybe you can give the full error message or have a look for yourself?

Comment: Thanks for the tips -- that it's looking for the symbols in a different version of the DLL to the one I've linked looks plausible, so I'll look into that.

Comment: By the way, I see that "unity" is also the name of a dependency injection framework from Microsoft, which is confusing.  The Unity I've been struggling to get this to work with is the game engine.  I'll update my question to make that clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out in the end.  It was, as Carsten König suggested, to do with the version of F#/Mono I was compiling against not being compatible with that used by Unity.  Since I was compiling a dll using a simple `fsharpc` command and then including that in my Unity `Assets` directory, I didn't have an `app.config` (or at least, if it's possible to use one I don't know how).

Instead I used `fsharpc`'s `--noframework` option to prevent the compiler from linking against its default assemblies, and then manually referenced the assemblies that come packaged with Unity.

The following makefile copies over the requisite DLLs into the `Assets` folder and compiles a DLL of our own scripts for use with Unity.  It just does the compile in one shot, so if you change any of the scripts it'll recompile everything, which if you use it you'll probably want to change, but it's a reasonable starting-point.

```
SRC:=
OUT_DIR:=../Assets/Frameworks

UNITY_FRAMEWORK_DIR:=/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/Managed
MONO_DIR:=/Applications/Unity/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.11/lib/mono/2.0
MSCORLIB:=/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/Mono/lib/mono/unity/mscorlib.dll
FSHARPCORELIB:=$(MONO_DIR)/FSharp.Core.dll

.PHONY: all
all: $(OUT_DIR)/MyScripts.dll $(OUT_DIR)/FSharp.Core.dll

$(OUT_DIR)/MyScripts.dll: $(SRC)
        @mkdir -p $(OUT_DIR)
        fsharpc --noframework -r:$(MSCORLIB) -r $(FSHARPCORELIB) -r:$(UNITY_FRAMEWORK_DIR)/UnityEngine.dll --target:library -o $@ $^

$(OUT_DIR)/FSharp.Core.dll: $(FSHARPCORELIB)
        @mkdir -p $(OUT_DIR)
        cp $^ $@
```

I'm running on a mac, so my paths reflect that -- if you are on Windows you will need to tweak the paths to suit.  Simply add the list of .fs files to `SRC` and you're good to go (I've kept this manual so I can specify compilation order)